# user's arguments are empty with QCoreApplication in mysterious cases

Tags: c++, linux, qt, segmentation-fault, console-application

I'm trying to create a console application with `Qt` and been facing really strange behavior when attempting to retrieve the arguments. My class is derived from `QCoreApplication` which has a function that should normally put all the args in some list of `strings`. But in some cases that call ends in a segmentation fault.

Here's the code:

main.cpp

```
#include "Diagramm.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Diagramm application(argc, argv);
    application.run();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Diagramm.h

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>


class Diagramm : public QCoreApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Diagramm(int argc, char *argv[]);
        void run();
    private:
        void testArguments();
    signals:
    public slots:
};
```

Diagramm.cpp

```
#include "Diagramm.h"

Diagramm::Diagramm(int argc, char *argv[]) : QCoreApplication(argc, argv)
{
    //std::cout << "calling Diagramm constructor" << std::endl;
}

void Diagramm::run()
{
    testArguments();
}

void Diagramm::testArguments()
{
    //get source and target files from arguments
    QStringList arguments = this->arguments();

    if(arguments.count() < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Missing arguments" << std::endl;
        return exit(1);
    }
}
```

When compiling and executing the code above, everything works fine, BUT when I uncomment the line in `Diagramm`'s constructor I've got a segmentation fault on the first line of function `testArguments` (the call to `arguments()`)

I've been on that for hours, reading Qt's doc, forums... Does anyone know where that can come from? Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Note : I'm not calling the `exec` function on purpose because I don't need any event loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Q(Core)Application* wants `argc` and `argv` *by reference*, so your constructor should read

```
Diagramm(int& argc, char **argv[])
```

If you don't to this, it may work in some cases and lead to segfaults or strange behavior in others, as you encountered. Seems to be a common error and isn't easy to spot when reading the documentation.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot ! For others, the code above should be : (in main.cpp) `Diagramm application(argc, &argv);` (in Diagramm.cpp) `Diagramm::Diagramm(int &argc, char **argv[]) : QApplication(argc, *argv)`

Comment: For Qt5 the right signature is now: `Diagramm(int& argc, char **argv)`

Answer (score 0):

[arguments()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qcoreapplication.html#arguments) is a static function so the line should be:

```
QStringList arguments = QCoreApplication::arguments();
```

Comment: That's clearer indeed, but otherwise shouldn't make any difference.